# rails named scope issues

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, named-scope

I have two named scopes... both which work separately, but when combined do not work.

```
  named_scope :total, :select => "COUNT(*) as days, AVG(price) as price, SUM(price) AS total", :group => :parent_id
  named_scope :currency, lambda { |code| { :select => "*, price * #{(CurrencyRate.get_rate("USD", (code ||= "USD") ,1))} AS price" } }
```

Example:

```
c=Booking.total.currency("EUR").find_all_by_parent_id(63)
```

The total named scope works but not the currency...

```
c=Booking.currency("EUR").total.find_all_by_parent_id(63)
```

The currency named scope works but not the totals...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a couple of problems.

- Both scopes define "as price" and they conflict, this will produce invalid SQL
- One scope has a group clause, but the other doesn't have an aggregate function on a non grouped attribute in the select clause.  This will result in invalid SQL.

Instead of a scope that complicates your sql, consider using a computed attribute on your booking model.

```
class Booking
    def currency(code="USD")
        price * CurrencyRate.get_rate(code) ,1)
    end
end
```

Now you can:

```
c=Booking.total.find_all_by_parent_id(63)
for booking in c
    puts booking.currency("EUR")
end
```

If you must use a scope, consider combining them.  I realize you probably don't want to create named scopes for each permutation, but I think something has to change.  You can create a named_scope :currency_total

```
named_scope :currency_total, lambda { |code| {:select => "COUNT(*) as days, 
           AVG(price * #{(CurrencyRate.get_rate("USD", (code ||= "USD") ,1))}) as price, 
           SUM(price * #{(CurrencyRate.get_rate("USD", (code ||= "USD") ,1))}) AS total", 
           :group => :parent_id }}
```

Comment: i went with the longer and last approach... it works fine.  thanks

Answer (score 3):

Sadly `named_scope` doesn't chain anything else than conditions successfully at the moment.

`:select` will be set by *only one* of the named scopes.  Therefore you should go with **jrhicks** approach.

Btw: That's why you should start every `:select => "model_name.*, ...` so that Rails gets the model's fields. You will run into other problems/errors otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure(via log) that the resulting query of the combined call is the sum of both queries, if it's, then the combination of the 2 queries is an empty set and you need to reconsider them both working together. if it's not, then please paste your model...